# POST parameter with value as an object in HTTP method

Tags: php, http

im working with an API for a company and completed initial task, the last task is to submit my work using their API. It's like onboarding challenge. One of the parameters value needs to be an object as said in documentation.

```
<?php 

$myWORK = array (
'Email' => 'MY_EMAIL',
'URL' => 'REPOSITORY_URL',
);

$url = 'https://api.xxxxxxx.com/';
$data = array(
  'key' => 'MY_API_KEY', 
  'base' => 'MY_TOKEN',
'data' => json_decode(json_encode($myWORK), FALSE)
  
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


$output = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($ouput);

?>
```

I need to pass that `$myWork` as value in the `data` parameter. It needs to be an object, does my object code correct? I get no error response from the API but the `data` is empty. Please give your thoughts.. a little help.

Comment: Why don't you just use `http_build_query($myWORK)`?

Comment: Already tried that, same issue.. they said they are catching the `data`  value with `json_decode`

Comment: Are you sure the API wants URL-encoded parameters rather than JSON?

Comment: it was my second thought that it must be a JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the API wants JSON, not url-encoded data.

```
$myWORK = array (
'Email' => 'MY_EMAIL',
'URL' => 'REPOSITORY_URL',
);

$url = 'https://api.xxxxxxx.com/';
$data = array(
    'key' => 'MY_API_KEY', 
    'base' => 'MY_TOKEN',
    'data' => $myWORK
  
);
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode($data),
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n"
    )
);
```

There's no need to call `json_decode(json_encode($myWORK))`, you can just nest the array directly into `$data`.

Comment: `json_encode($myWork)` not `json_encode($data)`?

Comment: They should be the same.

Comment: I just tried, it return a response that the `base` is missing eveen tho its not, maybe on encode process?

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the code. I saw `'data' =>` and thought that was `$data =`